# Classification of (not necessarily connected) compact Lie groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, lie-groups

I am looking for a classification of compact (not necessarily connected) Lie groups. Clearly, all such groups are extensions of a finite "component group" $\pi_0(G)$ by a compact connected Lie group $G_0$:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> G_0 @>>>  G @>p>>  \pi_0(G) @>>> 0
\end{CD}
The classification of compact connected Lie groups is familiar to me, so my question is how to classify such extensions.

---

UPDATE: I suspect the following is true (due to @LSpice, with my added requirement that $H$, $P$ are finite):

**Hypothesis**: $G$ can always be written as
$$
G= \frac{G_0 \rtimes H}{P}
$$
for finite groups $H,P$, where $P \subseteq Z(G_0 \rtimes H)$.

UPDATE 2: @LSpice has **proven this below** for the weaker requirement that $P$ intersects $G_0$ within $Z(G_0)$, and provided a counterexample where $P$ cannot be taken to be central.

UPDATE 3: See [Improved classification of compact Lie groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378160/) for a follow-up question (which I won't write here to avoid excessive clutter.)

---

A less useful claim from my original question: any such $G$ can be constructed from $G_0$ in three steps:

1. Take the direct product of $G_0$ with a finite group.
2. Quotient the result by a finite subgroup of its center.
3. Extend a finite subgroup of $\mathrm{Out}(G_0)$ by the result.

(Step 3 <s>may always be</s> is not a semidirect product in general.)

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call this a classification, but at best a reconstruction.

Comment: That's true. I'm not claiming that there is only one way to construct G by these three steps, only that all compact Lie groups (connected or not) take this form. If anyone knows a classification along similar lines, so much the better!

Comment: Where did you read (or how did you prove) that it's such a semidirect product?

Comment: Did you check Brown's book "Cohomology of groups?" He discusses the classification of group extensions with nonabelian kernel.

Comment: @YCor I may have been too glib in writing a semidirect product. It is an extension by outer automorphisms, which may (or may not; I don't know a counterexample) be a semidirect product.

Comment: It is a semidirect product "over the centre", but it need not be a semidirect product.  (By "over the centre", I mean that we have $G \cong (G^\circ \times F)/Z$, where $Z$ is central in $G^\circ \times F$.)  Example:  $\mathbb C^\times \rtimes \langle i\rangle/\langle{-1 \rtimes -1}\rangle$, where $i$ acts by inversion on $\mathbb C^\times$.  This example is (isomorphic to) the normaliser of a maximal torus in $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377981/classification-of-not-necessarily-connected-compact-lie-groups#comment959059_377981), $G^\circ \times F$ was supposed to be $G^\circ \rtimes F$.

Comment: Does "*extension by outer automorphisms*" refer to an extension $1\to N\to G\to Q\to 1$ where the resulting map $Q\to\mathrm{Out}(N)$ is injective?

Comment: Classifying finite groups is hard: the exact number of groups of order $2^n$ is known only for $n\leq 10$.  The number of 1-dimensional compact Lie groups with $2^n$ components is expected to lie somewhere between the number of groups of order $2^{n+1}$ and the number of groups of order $2^{n+2}$.

Comment: @YCor Yes, that is what I mean. In fact, in this case $T_G$ (your $Q$) is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathrm{Out}(G_0)$.

Comment: @LSpice Your example is not compact, I think. However, I thought of a compact example, which is $\mathrm{Pin}_{-}(2)$. It's not a semidirect product, since any reflection (i.e., any element in the non-identity component) squares to $-1$. However, it is a quotient of a semidirect product by a subgroup of its center.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks for the reference. There's a lot of mathematical formalism in that book that seems somewhat opaque to me without working through it front to back (which I am unlikely to get around to). Any place in particular I should look?

Comment: @BenHeidenreich, you're right of course, but it's an easy fix:  just replace $\mathbb C^\times$ by $S^1$ in [my example](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377981/classification-of-not-necessarily-connected-compact-lie-groups?noredirect=1#comment959059_377981).  This is very likely the same as [your](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377981/classification-of-not-necessarily-connected-compact-lie-groups#comment959368_377981) $\operatorname{Pin}_-(2)$, although I don't know that notation.

Comment: @LSpice I noticed after the fact that your comment makes the same claim as my hypothesis in the updated question. Do you know a proof of this, or a relevant reference? (Indeed, your example with $\mathbb{C}^*$ replaced by $S^1$ is the same as my example.)

Comment: @LSpice Likewise, I have deleted those of my comments that refer to previous versions, and are no longer possible to follow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\U{U}$Consider the matrices $u = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1  \\
-1 & 0 \\
&& 0 & 1 \\
&& 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $v = \begin{pmatrix}
0 && 1 \\
& 0 && 1 \\
-1 && 0 \\
& -1 && 0
\end{pmatrix}$.  These belong to the finite group of signed permutation matrices, so the group that they generate is finite and we call it $H$.  Put $G_0 = \left\{d(z, w) \mathrel{:=} \begin{pmatrix} z \\ & z^{-1} \\ && w \\ &&& w^{-1} \end{pmatrix} \mathrel: z, w \in \U(1)\right\}$.  Since $u d(z, w)u^{-1} = d(z^{-1}, w^{-1})$ and $v d(z, w)v^{-1} = d(w, z)$, the group $G$ generated by $G_0$, $u$, and $v$ has $G_0$ as its identity component.  Now let $G_0 \rtimes H \to G$ be any cover restricting to the inclusion $G_0 \to G$, and let $\tilde u$ be an element of $H$ whose image lies in $u G_0$; say the image is $u d(z, w)$.  Then $\tilde u^2$ maps to $(u d(z, w))^2 = u^2 = d(-1, 1)$, so $d(-1, 1) \rtimes \tilde u^2$ lies in $\ker(G_0 \rtimes H \to G)$.  If $\tilde v$ is an element of $H$ whose image lies in $v G_0$, then $\tilde v(d(-1, 1) \rtimes \tilde u^2)\tilde v^{-1}$ lies in $d(1, -1) \rtimes H$, hence does not equal $d(-1, 1) \rtimes H$.  That is, $\ker(G_0 \rtimes H \to G)$ is not central in $G_0 \rtimes H$.

---

What we can do is find (in general, not just for the specific example above) a finite subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that the multiplication map $G^\circ \times H \to G$ is surjective, and its kernel centralises $G^\circ$.  (In the specific example above, we could take $H = \langle u, v\rangle$.)

$\DeclareMathOperator\Ad{Ad}\DeclareMathOperator\Gal{Gal}\DeclareMathOperator\Norm{Norm}\DeclareMathOperator\Weyl{W}\DeclareMathOperator\Zent{Z}\newcommand\C{{\mathbb C}}\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\newcommand\adform{_\text{ad}}\newcommand\scform{_\text{sc}}\newcommand\X{\mathcal X}$To prove this, I'll use a few pieces of structure theory:

1. All maximal tori in $G$ are $G^\circ$-conjugate.
2. All Borel subgroups of $G_\C$ are $G^\circ_\C$-conjugate.
3. For every maximal torus $T$ in $G$, the map $\Weyl(G^\circ, T) \to \Weyl(G^\circ_\C, T_\C)$ is an isomorphism.
4. If $G\scform$ and $(G_\C)\scform$ are the simply connected covers of the derived groups of $G^\circ$ and $G^\circ_\C$, then $(G\scform)_\C$ equals $(G_\C)\scform$.
5. [Every compact Lie group has a finite subgroup that meets every component](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150949/in-any-lie-group-with-finitely-many-connected-components-does-there-exist-a-fin).

I only need (4) to prove that, for every maximal torus $T$ in $G$, the map from $T$ to the set of conjugation-fixed elements of $T/\Zent(G^\circ)$ is surjective.  This is probably a well known fact in its own right for real-group theorists.

Now consider triples $(T, B_\C, \X)$ as follows:  $T$ is a maximal torus in $G$; $B_\C$ is a Borel subgroup of $G^\circ_\C$ containing $T_\C$, with a resulting set of simple roots $\Delta(B_\C, T_\C)$; and $\X$ is a set consisting of a real ray in each complex simple root space (i.e., the set of positive real multiples of some fixed non-$0$ vector).  (Sorry about the pair of modifiers "complex simple".)  I will call these 'pinnings', although it doesn't agree with the usual terminology (where we pick individual root vectors, not rays).  I claim that $G^\circ/\Zent(G^\circ)$ acts simply transitively on the set of pinnings.

Once we have transitivity, freeness is clear:  if $g \in G^\circ$ stabilises some pair $(T, B_\C)$, then it lies in $T$, and so stabilises every complex root space; but then, for it to stabilise some choice of rays $\X$, it has to have the property that $\alpha(g)$ is positive and real for each simple root $\alpha$; but also $\alpha(g)$ is a norm-$1$ complex number, hence trivial, for each simple root $\alpha$, hence for each root $\alpha$, so that $g$ is central.

For transitivity, since (1) all maximal tori in $G$ are $G^\circ$-conjugate, so (2) for every maximal torus $T$ in $G$, the Weyl group $\Weyl(G^\circ_\C, T_\C)$ acts transitively on the Borel subgroups of $G^\circ_\C$ containing $T_\C$, and (3) $\Weyl(G^\circ, T) \to \Weyl(G^\circ_\C, T_\C)$ is an isomorphism, it suffices to show that all possible sets $\X$ are conjugate.  Here's the argument that I came up with to show that they are even $T$-conjugate; I think it can probably be made much less awkward.  Fix a simple root $\alpha$, and two non-$0$ elements $X_\alpha$ and $X'_\alpha$ of the corresponding root space.  Then there are a positive real number $r$ and a norm-$1$ complex number $z$ such that $X'_\alpha = r z X_\alpha$.  Choose a norm-$1$ complex number $w$ such that $w^2 = z$.  There is then a unique element $s\adform$ of $T_\C/\Zent(G^\circ_\C)$ such that $\alpha(s\adform) = w$, and $\beta(s\adform) = 1$ for all simple roots $\beta \ne \alpha$.  By (4), we can choose a lift $s\scform$ of $s\adform$ to $(G\scform)_\C = (G_\C)\scform$, which necessarily lies in the preimage $(T_\C)\scform$ of (the intersection with the derived subgroup of) $T$, and put $t\scform = s\scform\cdot\overline{s\scform}$.  Then
$$
\alpha(t\scform) = \alpha(s\scform)\overline{\overline\alpha(s\scform)} = \alpha(s\scform)\overline{\alpha(s\scform)^{-1}} = w\cdot\overline{w^{-1}} = z,
$$
and, similarly, $\beta(t\scform) = 1$ for all simple roots $\beta \ne \alpha$.  Now the image $t$ of $t\scform$ in $G^\circ_\C$ lies in $T_\C$ and is fixed by conjugation, hence lies in $T$; and $\Ad(t)X_\alpha = z X_\alpha$ lies on the ray through $X'_\alpha$.

Since $G$ also acts on the set of pinnings, we have a well defined map $p : G \to G^\circ/\Zent(G^\circ)$ that restricts to the natural projection on $G^\circ$.  Now $\ker(p)$ meets every component, but it contains $\Zent(G^\circ)$, so it need not be finite.  Applying (5) to the Lie group $\ker(p)$ yields the desired subgroup $H$.  Note that, as requested in your [improved classification](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378160/improved-classification-of-compact-lie-groups), conjugation by any element of $H$ fixes a pinning, hence, if inner, must be trivial.

Comment: @BenHeidenreich, we actually *cannot* arrange in general that $H \cap G^\circ$ is central in $H$; I have edited in a counterexample at the beginning.  Since I think that the answer is at last in its final form, and also addressed your [improved classification](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378160/improved-classification-of-compact-lie-groups), I have deleted my comments above.

Comment: Likewise, I have deleted my comments, as they refer to previous versions and are no longer possible to follow.